# Continue on Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

how can i catch/rescue from a Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout?

Basically I am running a command that opens a process and never returns, i want to just close the process that opens and move on with my chef recipe as it not returning doesn't really matter...

---

**Here is the code for my attempt:**

```
begin
    execute 'install_visual_studio_settings' do
        command "\"#{node.run_state['installed_path']}\\devenv.exe\" /ResetSettings #{node.run_state['tmp_dir']}\\XXXX.vssettings"
        timeout 80
    end
rescue Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout
    execute 'kill visual studio' do
        command "taskkill /IM \"devenv.exe\" /F"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the outcome of the first `execute` command doesn't really matter, you could lower the timeout and use the [`ignore_failure`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html) common property.

Maybe there's also a way using windows' `START /B <program>` command without having to wait for a timeout.